# winrt xaml PageLayout VisualState

Tags: xaml, grid, windows-runtime, storyboard, visualstates

I have a lot of UserControls placed on my Page. All of them are in grid rows and colums. Also there are several nested grids that contain UserControls. 
But now I need to provide Snapped VisualState with these UserControls but with completely different layout.

It is easy to select inner styles for UserControls but it is not clear for me how can I change for instance Grid.RowDefinitions with 2 rows to Grid.RowDefinitions with 3 rows, change every Grid.Row property for inner UserControls and even more to replace some childs elements from one grid to another.

Is it possible to make some Template for Grid elements?

Comment: Would it work better to make the Grid part of the DataTemplate? Then you have the DataTemplate changed based on layout selected.

Comment: Yes, you are completely write, but I didn't write some details, that I'm using metroprism (http://metroprism.codeplex.com/) and I need to set regions with my views to named content controls (region can be set to some control once). I didn't want to handle VisualState changing in code for do some regions navigation to another controls in snapped data template. But now I see that maybe it is required in   this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggles trying to dynamically layout and restyle controls depending on view state I decided to use the template approach and simply have separate views for different... views. Basically have separate logical tree for each view and switch visibilities of these depending on view state.

Comment: Thanks, it was usefull because I wasn't sure. But as I see to do it with prism and its regions I have to renavigate in code all my regions to active Visible DataTemplate when VisualState Changes. But I wanted to do all in xaml without code handling. If you can give some advice it would be great). But corresponding the question I asked your ansewer was write. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used the regions of Prism, but I think the visibility of specific regions shouldn't need to be updated when the screen view state changes, since you would handle that globally in your view. Unless having two regions associated with same view model is a problem. I'm not really sure - I would simply use MVVM Light and avoid worrying about regions. :)